# simple models template Access via Foreign key? What did i miss?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i am testing different views and models in django 2.1.5.

I made two simple models and a simple view function to Access Albums by Artist in my template. So far i only see the last names of my artists.

i tried to Access the Album model  via **{% for album in object_list.album_set.all %}** but nothing happens, i guess i miss something. i searched online to help myself but most tutorials are only show django examples in pyhton shell. Someone mention also to give the Model with the FKey a related_name, so i named it after a datafield.

every hint welcome, thanks

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
person_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='artist/', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True )

def __str__(self):
    return "{} - {}".format(self.car[:25], self.color[:25])

class Album(models.Model):
    albumname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    artistkey = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="albumname")

 def __str__(self):
        return self.albumname
```

**views.py**

```
def artist_page(request):
object_list = Person.objects.all()
context = {'object_list': object_list}
return render(request, 'aquaman/aquaforkey.html', context)
```

**aquaforkey.html**

```
{% block content %}

<h1>HELLO</h1>

  {% for artist in object_list %}
     <h1> {{ artist.last_name }}</h1>
       {% for album in object_list.album_set.all %}
      {{ album.albumname }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues here. The item is `artist`, not `object_list`. And you've set the related_name to `albumname`.

```
{% for album in artist.albumname.all %}
```

(Those posts that told you to change the related_name were *wrong*, by the way. Only change it if you have a very good reason.)

Comment: i had also  l mixed up  self.albumname <models.py> it was set to self.name. After i changed it, it worked. Thanks. But when i delete "related_name="albumname"" in my models, like you said than again nothing showed up.

Comment: Yes because then it would go back to `artist.album_set.all`.